# Copy what I write in TextArea when I press a button

Tags: java, post, button

I want to make it so people can type in a Text Area and when they're done typing they press a "Post!" Button which basically just adds their post as text like it works on facebook. You write something blablabla about your day, press Post!
How would I do this?

I'm doing this in NetBeans if that matters heres how my GUI looks if that helps. (I do code first then design) xd
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jukyj.jpg

Basically what I want is, for example I type "Hello my name is cow!" in the textarea and when I press the "POST" button I want the jLabel1 to turn into the text I wrote in the textarea.

Comment: For what you are doing you can just place the TextArea contents into a String variable, for example: `String myText = jTextArea1.getText();`. To post what was typed in the TextArea and place it into the console window, follow with: `System.out.println(myText);`.

Comment: Yeah that could work. But lets say I have a label under the button I want that label to turn into the text you write into the textarea would taht be possible? :) thx btw!

Comment: That then would be something like this in your button's **ActionPerformed** event: `jLabel1.setText(jTextArea1.getText());`. Where jLabel1 is the JLabel located under your JButton.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using JFrame!

First you need to extend you class to use it and import the API like so:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
public class Example extends JFrame{}
```

Once you have variables for the button and text field you need to attach listeners like so:

```
button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            //LOGIC to grab data
        }
```

Last to get the data from the text box you can create a simple method to be able to grab data from the textbox:

```
public static JTextField getData() {
    return data;
}
```

Here is some documentation on the library here:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html